# Margin calculation error in IE11 in remote hosted page, but not in local

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I've been creating a static web page, and testing it in the latest Chrome, Firefox, and IE. On my local filesystem copy, the HTML pages render just fine, but on my hosted copy, the title's `margin: 0 auto` value is calculated incorrectly and pushes the title to the right... sometimes. The page renders correctly when I navigate via the address bar, but if I reload the page, it causes the error.

[Here's the normal page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEXvS.jpg)

[Here's the error showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbStG.jpg)

[Here's the remotely hosted site](http://edooner320.co.nf/indexW05.html)

Any ideas what could be causing it? The doctype is declared as `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` so I don't think it's a quirks mode issue. EDIT: I've confirmed that IE11 is rendering in Standards mode in all cases.

Comment: Post your code or site link

Comment: Updated with link to site.

Comment: You say you don't think it's a quirks mode issue, but have you actually *checked* the browser mode? IE's devtools will tell you what mode it's running in, which will allow you to rule out it being a mode issue for certain rather than just thinking it probably isn't that.

Comment: I've verified that IE is running in standards mode, both when displaying the title normally, and when it displays incorrectly.

Comment: I added a clear:both to the SPAN inside your H1 tag and that fixed it. Not sure why that helped, but it worked.

Comment: @ChrisLove: I checked, and clearing the span didn't help. What you might have encountered if a quirk that if you change a style on the header, it resets the text back to it's proper position. This happens by toggling the existing styles too.